# AWS kinesis to Aws redshift lambda function without using S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to write a lambda function to load streaming data from AWS kinesis or kinesis firehose directly to Aws redshift without using intermediate S3 bucket. Let me know if someone can support on this?

Comment: Is there already something you tried to do?  What configurations and code have you tried so far? Also, please elaborate on why you chose for the setup above/what are your restrictions.

Comment: try to be more specific with your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The high bandwidth method of loading data into Redshift is with the COPY command.  This command supports parallel loading of data directly into Redshift compute nodes which is a huge asset when large amounts of data are involved.  The COPY command supports 4 different sources - S3, DynamoDB, EMR, and SSH hosts.  (In all 4 cases it is important to enable parallel loading if the data is large)

So to use the COPY command but not use S3 you will need some additional resources configured and it isn't clear how you will move the data to any of these resources in your Lambda (though is it definitely doable).  Since I don't understand the objection to S3 I cannot speak to whether or not one of these paths will meet your needs.  However, it doesn't seem like you will get an efficient solution if you need to create another set of compute infrastructure just to bypass S3.

(This path is not recommended) You can load data into tables through SQL - just bake the values into the SQL and run it.  Loading even moderately sized data this way is very inefficient and will likely create problems for you. You have been warned!  "INSERT INTO  VALUES ( ... );" is valid and will run.  The problem is that your data is running through your Redshift leader node and through the query compiler.  Ick! You will also be limited by the query size limit of 64K characters and the data will be written out as plain text so each INSERT can only hold a very limited amount of data. Ugh! Each INSERT will allocate a new block increasing the amount of VACUUM work that will be required.  Just shoot me now!  If you are using Kinesis your data is likely of significant size so this isn't likely the path you want to go down either.

There's a reason that S3 is the most often used path for moving data into Redshift.  You may be better off asking 'we have concern X with S3, is there a way to address this concern while loading data into Redshift?'.